# Asset not loaded in libgdx using AssetManager

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to use a `AssetManger` in my game.But i am getting error that image not loading.
From homoscreen i am loading each screen.

AssetHelper.java

```
public static AssetManager manager=new AssetManager();
    public static void AssetQueLoad()
        {
            //AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
            manager.load("images/"+usesDpi+"/Screen1/Scn1Bg.jpg", Texture.class);
        }

        public static void  loadScreen1()
        {

            Scn1Bg=manager.get("images/"+usesDpi+"/Screen1/Scn1Bg.jpg", Texture.class);

        }
```

In render i'll **load AssetsHelper.AssetQueLoad();**

In homoscreen.java

```
while(!AssetsHelper.manager.update()){

    System.out.println(">"+AssetsHelper.manager.getProgress()*100);
        //if(AssetsHelper.manager.isLoaded(fileName))
        {
            game.setScreen(game.screen1);
        }
}
```

i will redirect other page.

in screen1.java

```
AssetsHelper.loadScreen1();
Scn1BgTexture= AssetsHelper.Scn1Bg;
```

try to load,but i am getting error `Asset not loaded: images/xdpi/Screen1/Scn1Bg.jpg` .Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

tray this :

```
if (AssetsHelper.manager.update()) { 

    game.setScreen(game.screen1);

}
while(!AssetsHelper.manager.update()){

System.out.println(">"+AssetsHelper.manager.getProgress()*100);

}
```

P.S: you can put the stacktrace.

this comments is correct or mistake:

```
//if(AssetsHelper.manager.isLoaded(fileName))
    {
        game.setScreen(game.screen1);
    }
```

secondly, that file is filename, note that if filename is loaded and do the set screen, the rest can this not loaded, when you want to use it, assuming filename is not the image you want to load